# CORS issue using port 6000... but no issue using port 6001 - why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-domain

I have a simple Node.js server running and a client React app to test authentication functionality.  When I use port 6000, I run into this error:

[Error] CORS-preflight request was blocked
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:6000/auth/register due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: CORS-preflight request was blocked (register, line 0)

However, when I change the port number to 6001 (updating both the port on the server and the client), or any other port (for example port 8000), the error goes away, and my authentication post request goes through just fine on both the front end and the back end. Why is that?

Comment: Your browser might have the request cached.

Comment: Port 6000 is among the set of ports that browsers block. See the lists at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mozilla_Port_Blocking and https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/heads/master/net/base/port_util.cc#20